# Why does this program throw errors?

Tags: python, http, url

I was using the same program yesterday and it is supposed to open the browser and insert our query there. It was working well yesterday. Today it's throwing errors.

```
from googlesearch import *
import webbrowser
#to search, will ask search query at the time of execution
query = input("Input your query:")
for url in search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, stop = 1, pause = 2):
    webbrowser.open("https://google.com/search?q=%s" % query)'
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/arehojayaar.py", line 5, in <module>
    for url in search(query, tld="co.in", num=1, stop = 1, pause = 2):
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 288, in search
    html = get_page(url, user_agent)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 154, in get_page
    response = urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Comment: How many requests are you trying to make? In how quick succession?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests` which means you made too many requests to the Endpoint and the Server decided to ratelimit you. You'll have to wait until you're allowed to do requests again.

Comment: Nope the error doesn't tell you how long it will last so theres no way to know. Maybe try tomorrow.

Comment: Bombarding a server like that is not nice. The server configuration will determine for how long your IP is blocked, but you'll be blocked again if you rerun this program without throttling your request rate.

Comment: so what should I do to throttle the request rate any suggestions please?

Comment: Looking at your current code I would just drop the search() and the for loop since you're not using the results anyway, you just open a google search with your search query.

Comment: Hey , that just worked without  giving  'HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests' error, Thank you i'm happy!